# ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I am trying to understand what is happened here but somehow I can not. Whatever I tried again and again I get error. The error message which I  get is :

```
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
*Action:   Consult your manual.
```

So far what I am  trying to do is here

```
SELECT
            A.UserID, 
            A.Surname, 
            A.Lastname,
            A.PersonalNumber,
            A.EmployeeNumber, 
            (SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage), 1) from user_mileages um 
            INNER JOIN user_timesheets ut 
            ON um.TimesheetId = ut.UserTimesheetsID
            WHERE ut.Date_ BETWEEN '2020-02-24' AND '2020-06-06'
            AND um.UserId = A.UserID ) AS sum_mileage_per_month,
            A.UserTimesheetsID,
            A.User_roleID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.UserID) AS RowNumber
         FROM (
         SELECT 
            u.UserID, 
            u.Surname, 
            u.Lastname,
            u.User_roleID,
            u.PersonalNumber,
            u.EmployeeNumber, 
            (um.Mileage),
            ut.UserTimesheetsID
         FROM 
            users  u
         LEFT JOIN 
            user_timesheets  ut 
         ON 
            ut.user_id = u.UserID
         LEFT JOIN
            user_mileages  um
         ON
            (ut.UserTimesheetsID = um.TimesheetId AND ut.user_id = um.UserId)
         WHERE 
            ut.Date_ BETWEEN '2020-02-24' AND '2020-06-06' 
         UNION
            SELECT u.UserID, 
                    u.Surname, 
                    u.Lastname, 
                    u.User_roleID, 
                    u.PersonalNumber, 
                    u.EmployeeNumber, 
                    NULL AS Mileage,
                    NULL AS UserTimesheetsID 
            FROM users  u
         ) A
         ORDER BY A.EmployeeNumber, A.Surname, A.Lastname
```

So far the error is in

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage), 1) from user_mileages um
```

Here `um.Mileage` field is Float data type and as far as I try to convert to `TO_CHAR` and `TO_NUMBER` and using `CAST` but no one solution works so far.
What is wrong here ? Why I can not convert this to char or to number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage)) FROM table_name;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUM(um.Mileage)) FROM table_name;
```

**Error:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage), 1) FROM table_name;
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a date value `ut.Date_` with a varchar2 value `'2020-02-24'`. Instead, compare date types with date types.

In this case, you could use a literal and become `ut.Date_ BETWEEN date '2020-02-24' AND date '2020-06-06'`. If you also need the time section in the comparison, use function to_date().

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: No, it's not soulution. Still have problem

Comment: You have the situation twice in your sql query, did you change it 2x? Add the date literal in both situations (line 10 and 36 in the query above)

Comment: Yes, I change it 2x but still have problem. As I see the problem is (SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage), 1)
Since I comment this line of code and it return me data, but when I uncomment it I get error

Comment: `to_char( sum( um.Mileage), 1)`?? What are you trying to do here? Shouldn't it just be
`SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage))`?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `um.mileage` ?

Comment: Yes, it shold be  SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(um.Mileage)). I  get the point right now. It works 
However, thank  you !

Comment: um.mileage is Float data type

Comment: No *to_char( sum( um.Mileage), 1)* does not work. The second parameter for the to_char function is the format you want the result returned as. 1 is not a valid format, and your error message specifically says *invalid number format*. It is the source of your error.